# Delphi Unicode and Console

Tags: delphi

I am writing a C# application that interfaces with a pair of hardware sensors.  Unfortunately the only interface that is exposed on the devices requires a provided dll written in Delphi.

I am writing a Delphi executable wrapper that takes calls the necessary functions for the DLL and returns the sensor data over stout.  However, the return type of this data is a PWideChar (or PChar) and I have been unable to convert it to ansi for printing on command line.

If I directly pass the data to WriteLn, I get '?' for each character.  If I look through the array of characters and attempt to print them one at a time with an Ansi Conversion, only a few of the characters print (they do confirm the data though) and they will often print out of order. (printing with the index exposed simply jumps around.)  I also tried converting the PWideChar's to integer straight: 'I' corresponds to 21321. I could potentially figure out all the conversions, but some of the data has a multitude of values.

I am unsure of what version of Delphi the dll uses, but I believe it is 4.  Definately prior to 7.

Any help is appreciated!

TLDR: Need to convert UTF-16 PWideChar to AnsiString for printing.

**Example application:**

```
program SensorReadout;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  dllFuncUnit in 'dllFuncUnit.pas'; //This is my dll interface.

var  state: integer;
     answer: PChar;
     I: integer;
     J: integer;
     output: string;
     ch: char;

begin
  try
    for I := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      answer:= GetDeviceChannelInfo_HSI(1, Ord('a'), I, state); //DLL Function, returns a PChar with the results.  See example in comments.

      if state = HSI_NO_ERRORCODE then
      begin
        output:= '';
        for J := 0 to length(answer) do
        begin
          ch:= answer[J]; //This copies the char. Originally had an AnsiChar convert here.
          output:= output + ch;
        end;
        WriteLn(output);
      end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn(I);
end.`
```

The issue was PAnsiChar needed to be the return type of the function sourced from the DLL.

Comment: How does the text you wish to output look like? Perhaps it *cannot* be represented as an AnsiString? For instance, the Unicode string `⌬‽∫∇❦∴φ┶` cannot be 'converted' to an AnsiString.

Comment: The text is appearing as ???.  The expected output for one example is: "ISO 4190250" but I am getting "????????".  If I convert char by char, I will get the S and a 4, but the others either are empty or cause strange IO problems.

Comment: Probably some subtle bug somewhere. I think you need to show a minimal project (with code) that displays this problem.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Code included above.

Comment: according to that code if "state" is a code <> HSI_NO_ERRORCODE and there is no exception then it will write the uninitialised string "output" to the console. Which could be anything including accidentally showing "S" and "4":(

Comment: @DavidHeffenan Problem is the input is only available on my remote device and I haven't gotten remote debugging working yet. I'll get back to you on some PWideChar dump if I can.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Give me some credit.  I've already tried doing a straight assignment into string, and I still get the Characters to resolve to '?'.  I need to get the Ascii converted value of the original encoded text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's the other dev who was helping with the project. He posted that before I got around to posting this one. I felt that more details needed to be included.

Comment: @Jonneh Straight assignment to string is correct. That is the solution to the question that you asked. That will convert from UTF16 to Ansi. It's trivial for you to test this yourself. You can pass a `PWideChar` to the function in my answer and see that I am right. Once you have convinced yourself that the code is fine, then you can concentrate on what's in your input data.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What boggles my mind is that they show up as ? for an unsupported character, there was an Ansi function that worked correclty for a few of the characters only, and they display fine with a StrPas in a gui (text object).  However, they are still ?'s in commandline.

Comment: Even if you don't know which version of Delphi the DLL was compiled with, you surely know which version of Delphi *you're* using, don't you? Please specify in the question. As I told your colleague, it makes a considerable difference when dealing with the `PChar` type. What makes you think converting a PWideChar to an AnsiString is the task you need to accomplish at all? And why do you think you need to convert the string to Ansi to print it on the console, either? (And why are you even writing this program at all? C# programs can load and call most Delphi DLLs directly.)

Comment: This Delphi DLL is not written correctly to be implemented directly in C#, let alone C/C++

Comment: If I may interject. The DLL that we have does not have a TYPEDEF, and so can not be used directly in C#. We do not have the .lib and .h files, and so can not use it in C/C++. Out remaining option is to create a wrapper in Delphi that can be accessed by one of these languages.

Comment: Looks OK to me. You just don't know how to interpret the results. You *claim* you're getting a PWideChar, but I don't think you really are. You say the first character has numeric value 21321. When interpreted as two AnsiChars, that's `IS`. You're getting a `PAnsiChar`, not a `PWideChar`. You don't have to convert anything. You just have to fix the import unit to use the proper type, which is `PAnsiChar`, not `PChar`.

Comment: @RobKennedy I am using Embarcadero® Delphi® XE2.  I only know that the GUI implementation converts the string with StrPas();  However, this produces different results in the console, instead the ?'s.  After doing much searching and having MILD succes, I identified that the character encoding appears to be the issue here.  A ansi conversion of a few of the characters works correctly and after multiple passes.  However, it seems to not work on all of them.

Comment: What does a "typedef" have to do with anything, @User? That's a C and C++ keyword for defining type aliases and has nothing to do with using DLLs in C#. You can use DLLs that you don't have lib files for; just run implib or whatever that tool is. Or use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. You can write the .h file yourself; there's nothing magical about .h files.

Comment: @RobKennedy I am working off import functions from code I was handed by the manufacturer.  Despite this, and despite the fact that they make this work somehow, I think you've potentially solved my issue.  Thank you for looking into this further with me.

Comment: The manufacturer gave you code written for Delphi 4. In Delphi 4, `PChar` was the same as `PAnsiChar`, so the code is right, *in that version*. You're compiling Delphi 4 code with Delphi XE2, where the meaning of `PChar` is different.

Comment: Please consider taking extended discussions to [chat].

Comment: @Jonneh To be fair, we said very early on that your input data was probably not UTF-16.

Comment: @RobKennedy I diect you to this question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031875/cant-import-dll-in-c-application where it seems that the dll can not be used in this fasion. I meant TYPELIB, not TYPEDEF, that was my mistake.

Comment: @user489041 If you read my answer you will see that you can call the DLL directly from C# using p/invoke. Whilst it seems that the DLL does not present a COM interface, you can use p/invoke to call it with no trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `PWideChar` to `AnsiString`:

```
function WideCharToAnsiString(P: PWideChar): AnsiString;
begin
  Result := P;
end;
```

The code converts from UTF-16, null-terminated PWideChar to `AnsiString`. If you are getting question marks in the output then either your input is not UTF-16, or it contains characters that cannot be encoded in your ANSI codepage.

My guess is that what is actually happening is that your Delphi DLL was created with a pre-Unicode Delphi and so uses ANSI text. But now you are trying to link to it from a post-Unicode Delphi where `PChar` has a different meaning. I'm sure Rob explained this to you in your other question. So you can simply fix it by declaring your DLL import to return `PAnsiChar` rather than `PChar`. Like this:

```
function GetDeviceChannelInfo_HSI(PortNumber, Address, ChNumber: Integer;
  var State: Integer): PAnsiChar; stdcall; external DLL_FILENAME;
```

And when you have done this you can assign to a string variable in a similar vein as I describe above.

What you need to absorb is that in older versions of Delphi, `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar`. In modern Delphi it is an alias for `PWideChar`. That mismatch would explain everything that you report.

---

It does occur to me that writing a Delphi wrapper to the DLL and communicating via stdout with your C# app is a very roundabout approach. I'd just p/invoke the DLL directly from the C# code. You seem to think that this is not possible, but it is quite simple.

```
[DllImport(@"mydll.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDeviceChannelInfo_HSI(
    int PortNumber, 
    int Address, 
    int ChNumber,
    ref int State
);
```

Call the function like this:

```
IntPtr ptr = GetDeviceChannelInfo_HSI(Port, Addr, Channel, ref State);
```

If the function returns a UTF-16 string (which seems doubtful) then you can convert the `IntPtr` like this:

```
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr);
```

Or if it is actually an ANSI string which seems quite likely to me then you do it like this:

```
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

And then of course you'll want to call into your DLL to deallocate the string pointer that was returned to you, assuming it was allocated on the heap.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just caused my string to change from ???? to a single ? Character.

Comment: Edited TLDR to better reflect.  Thanks for your attempt with the issue.

Comment: The function outputs a PChar (PWideChar) and it does contain the text I need, but the character encoding seems incompatible with Delphi's WriteLn.  Hence the ???.  Based on the values, it seems to be a form of UTF16.  Your conversion method does not work to convert the UTF16 to Ansi for use.

Comment: @David: I suspect @Jonneh might actually be right. Usually you don't use the `^` 'suffix operator'. Your code works better without it!

Comment: @David: Well, I even tried it, and it works as expected with a plain assignment (`Result := P`), but if you insist of doing `Result := P^`, then `Result` will only contain the first character of `P`. And that almost makes sense, because if `P` is a `PWideChar`, then `P^` is a `WideChar`, that is, a single character. Try it!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No worries, just trying to get this solved as timely as I can.  Its been part of a long series of nightmares.  When I started the project, I was not anticipating learning Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my mind on the comment - I'll make it an answer:)

According to that code if "state" is a code <> HSI_NO_ERRORCODE and there is no exception then it will write the uninitialised string "output" to the console. Which could be anything including accidentally showing "S" and "4" and a series of 1 or more question marks

Comment: That was originally in my block there. whoops. Sadly, it doesn't fix anything though.

Comment: There's no such thing as an uninitialized string. That string will be empty if nothing else gets assigned to it.

Comment: OK yes - misread it it not a local variable so it should be intialised

Answer (score 0):

type of answer(variable) is PChar. use length function good for string  variable.
use strlen instead of length.

```
 for J := 0 to StrLen(answer)-1 do
```

also accessible range of PChar(char *) is 0..n-1

Answer (score 0):

To convert UTF-16 PWideChar to AnsiString you can use simple cast:

```
var
  WStr: WideString;
  pWStr: PWideString;
  AStr: AnsiString;
begin
  WStr := 'test';
  pWStr := PWideString(WStr);
  AStr := AnsiString(WideString(pWStr));
end;
```