# Creating a 64-bit application in Visual Studio with SysNative

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit, include-path

I'm trying to build a 64-bit application using Visual Studio in C++

I need to access `Sens.dll` in Windows directory. **Since Visual Studio is a 32-bit application**, I have to use **SysNative** instead of **System32**

```
#import "C:/Windows/SysNative/Sens.dll"
```

because of File System Redirection.

If I change the path to `C:/Windows/System32/Sens.dll`, Visual Studio cannot access it since it redirects to `SysWOW64` while building. To mitigate this I can use `SysNative` but then the executable built is a 64-bit application and `SysNative` is inaccessible.

Is there any way to solve it?

A better explanation of SysNative is given in [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)

Comment: Where are the paths used? I don't see how the path in VS config and path in your app related to each other because they must be set separately. And don't link to external resources like that. Link to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) instead

Comment: I'm trying to import Sens.dll These paths are used as `#import "C:/windows/system32/sens.dll"`

Comment: that still doesn't explain how the paths relate to each other. If you're loading the DLL manually then VS doesn't read the path in your code. If you let Windows load the DLL automatically then your app knows nothing about the DLL path (and it doesn't need to know that). You need to show the real setup

Comment: Using sysnative is just fine, the #import directive only has an affect at compile-time.  So your real problem has nothing to do with it, whatever it might be.

Answer (score -1):

Don't import with absolute paths like this

```
#import "C:/windows/system32/sens.dll"
```

You should only use relative paths when using `include`, `using` or `import`. Add the path to the lookup list in project settings instead and then just `#import "sens.dll"`

In this case the DLL is in System32 so just add `$(SystemRoot)\SysNative` to *Additional Include Directories*

Comment: It still doesn't work. It says `No such file or directory found.`

Comment: Additional Include Directories: `$(SystemRoot)`

Comment: Tried using `$(SystemRoot)\System32` & `C:\Windows\System32` Still didn't work

Comment: @YogeshKumar use `$(SystemRoot)\SysNative` because that's where VS is expected to find. No `"system32"` is needed in the source code

Answer (score -1):

Accoreding to the [#import directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2019)

> Syntax:
>
> `#import "filename" [attributes]`
>
> `#import <filename> [attributes]`

We couldn't directly import using absolute paths. I suggest you could try to use the following steps:

1. Search where `sens.dll` is present in your code base or c:

   **C:\Windows\System32**
2. When you find any path in step 1, and then you should add that path to *Additional Library Directories* of Your Project.

   Right Click on Project > Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories. Add the path to *Additional Library Directories*

Comment: I suggest you could try to open the DLL in Visual Studio (simply with File | Open | File, it will open in Resource Editor by default) and see whether or not the  TYPELIB resource is present. For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031875/cant-import-dll-in-c-application

Comment: the issue is not with DLL or import path. The issue is Visual Studio being 32 bit and the application I'm making is 64 bit. Read the question **Since Visual Studio is 32 bit application, I have to use SysNative instead of System32 but SysNative is invisible to 64 bit applications**

Comment: "SysNative" isn't a real directory. It gets redirected to the real "System32" directory by the WOW64 emulation system. Only 32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows via WOW64 can use this virtual directory. If you want to build a 64-bit application using Visual Studio in C++. I suggest you could refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-configure-visual-cpp-projects-to-target-64-bit-platforms?view=vs-2019